# Trying to get polymer working in node-webkit

Tags: polymer, node-webkit

How can i make polymer work in a node-webkit application?
I have succesfully followed the polymer tutorials, and everything works fine when i just use a server like wamp.

to be clear : I have no problems working with nodewebkit itself, the question is how to get polymer working in nodewebkit.

Comment: What have you tried?  Is it not working for you?  Can you post an example of something that works in the browser but not in node-webkit?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, actually everything works now. It was a problem with node webkit version 11.2 and windows 8.1. Using node webkit v11.1 everything is fine.